# On-the-fly video streaming over http?

Tags: http, stream, on-the-fly, transcode

I'm building an application that will serve up video files to users on a variety of different platforms.  As such, I need the ability to set up a server that will serve up video files that might need to be transcoded into a number of different formats.  Basically, I want to replicate the functionality that TVersity provides.

The ideal solution would allow me to access the video stream via http, specifiying some sort of transcoding parameters in the call.

Anyone have any good ideas?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: why http? are these served in real-time without lag? udp transport may be a better option

Comment: I wouldn't suggest "udp over http" (as they are different layers), but I would suggest *use an existing protocol designed for this sort of thing*. E.g: MMS, RTSP, RTP, RTMP, etc. Over, even, "just http". It really depends on what these "different platforms" can handily consume.

Comment: I specified http because I want to be able to point, for example, an html5 video tag to "http://localhost:3000/video?format=ogv.  Something along those lines.  If I can accomplish that without using http, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is **not** a streaming protocol. Have a look at progressive download - there are lots of PHP implementations / flash players available. ffmpeg is a good tool for converting formats / size / frame rates etc.

Comment: If it's not a streaming protocol, what's the 206 Partial Content code used for?

Comment: is an HTTP-**based** media streaming communications protocol implemented by **Apple**